# Set CheckForGLErrors State

Tags: openscenegraph

I have a problem with multiple "Warning: detected OpenGL error 'invalid value' after RenderBin::draw(...)" error messages emitted by OSG. I found [this thread](https://www.mail-archive.com/osg-users@lists.openscenegraph.org/msg03657.html) showing a way to add additional debug information. Unfortunately I can't find a way to set the State.

I can create a State and set the flag using the code:

```
osg::ref_ptr<osg::State> debugState = new osg::State();  
debugState->setCheckForGLErrors(osg::State::CheckForGLErrors::ONCE_PER_ATTRIBUTE);
```

But what do I do after? I can't find a way to add the State to a StateSet.

Comment: can you please help me to install OpensceneGraph on Ubuntu.. i am struggling to install it, don't know where to start and where it should end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obviously use gDEBugger as some of the answers in the thread suggest. If you still want to really do it via `osg::State` then you can probably add a `osg::Drawable::DrawCallback` to all your drawables. Then within the `drawImplementation` of the `DrawCallback` you can do something like -

```
virtual void drawImplementation (osg::RenderInfo & renderinfo, const osg::Drawable * drawable) const 
{
  State& state = *renderInfo.getState();
  state->setCheckForGLErrors(osg::State::CheckForGLErrors::ONCE_PER_ATTRIBUTE);
  drawable->drawImplementation(); 
}
```

I am not very sure if changing the state this late would work perfectly, you need to check this. If it doesn't work you can also do something like `state.checkGLErrors("start of Geometry::drawImplementation()");` and `state.checkGLErrors("end of Geometry::drawImplementation()");` before and after calling `drawable->drawImplementation()` .

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in the end I recompiled osg with the flag as default.